# Error: disable image loading on watir with firefox

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

i've got an error by changing the profile for the watir-webdriver. I use the following code to disable loading images in firefox:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"
profile['permissions.default.image'] = 2
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

This error message occur:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:80:in `initialize': unknown option: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x00000000e90700 @model="/home/amvisor/.mozilla/firefox/9ud9suhs.default", @native_events=false, @secure_ssl=false, @untrusted_issuer=true, @load_no_focus_lib=false, @additional_prefs={"permissions.default.image"=>2}, @extensions={}>} (ArgumentError)
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:34:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:49:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:49:in `for'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:82:in `for'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.3/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from xxx.rb:38:in `new'
        from xxx.rb:38:in `<main>'
```

What means:

```
initialize: unknown option: {:Profile
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This works to use an existing Firefox profile with Firefox 48+:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Zipper.zip('/path/to/profile/xxx.default')
caps = Remote::Capabilities.firefox(firefox_options: {profile: profile})
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Ruby bindings do not yet fully support all of the features of Firefox profiles from the old Firefox Driver in the new geckodriver. If you need these additional features you can use Firefox <48 (I recommend installing Extended Support Release) and pass in `marionette: false` in capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Okay, i understand to edit the profile during running is not possible. But watir is loading a default profile at startup, is there no possibility to change the option in this default profile or in the code or XML? I tried to change it direct in firefox, but this takes no effect.